# Add a Column bases on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, list-comprehension

I want to add a new column to a df based on the values in a particular column. eg using regex and str.contain() to get the first matching 3 letters in the wellname then add a new field (fieldname) with value bat

Current columns in df:

```
wellname      size
bin 01          3
bin 02          6
bin 03          2
bin 04          5
john 01         2
john 02         8
john 02         5
pet 05          7
pet 06          10
```

column to add:

```
fieldname
tiger
leopard
bat
```

```
def add_col(df):
    for names in df['wellname']:
        if df['wellname'].str.contains(['bin']):
            df['fieldname'] = 'tiger'
        elif df['wellname'].str.contains(['john']):
            df['fieldname'] = 'leopard''
        elif df['wellname'].str.contains(['pet']):
            df['fieldname'] = 'bat'
    return(df)
```

I was expecting to get the df below:

fieldname   wellname      size
tiger        bingo         3
leopard      jean          5
fish         john          2
bat          peter         8

A function and an equivalent list comprehension will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple mapping:

```
repl = {'bin': 'tiger',
        'jea': 'leopard',
        'joh': 'fish',
        'pet': 'bat',
       }

df['fieldname'] = df['wellname'].map(repl)
```

But given your code, it looks like you want to map any substring:

```
repl = {'bin': 'tiger',
        'jea': 'leopard',
        'joh': 'fish',
        'pet': 'bat',
       }
pattern = '|'.join(repl)

df['fieldname'] = (df['wellname']
                   .str.extract(f'({pattern})', expand=False)
                   .map(repl)
                  )
```

Output:

```
  wellname  size fieldname
0    bingo     3     tiger
1     jean     5   leopard
2     john     2      fish
3    peter     8       bat
```

Comment: Apologies Mozway. Apparently  I did not ask the question correctly. I have edited it and will really appreciate your input. Thank you very much

Comment: @Chuks have you tried the second approach in my answer?

Comment: thanks very much. I have a long list of well  names like bin 01 - 50, john 01 - 70 and pet 01 - 80. These well names could change or there may be additions and I thought your mapping is hard code that may not allow scalability. I think something dynamic may work better. I thought of regex because the first 3 letters in each well names is constant so that with additional well names the function maps automatically.

Comment: In any case you have to define the one to one mappings, no? Else how would you know that "jea" should map to "leopard"?

Comment: Apologies @mozway, I edited the question. I was thinking a solution might be around using function to read each wellname and regex to identify wellnames that match exactly the first 3 letter eg [bin] and map it to the appropriate fieldname

Comment: If you want to limit to the start of the string: `f'^({pattern})'`, please give a coutner-example if you have issues as I believe my solution should work